# Why I have to use group by on 2 columns? Why group by on 1 column give me error?

Tags: sql, group-by

In this case both matchid and mdate are distinct value, so why I still have to GROUP BY both columns? What is the logic behind GROUP BY multiple columns?

1,Right result:

[image: Right Result]

2,Wrong result:

[image: Wrong Result]

Comment: Because you are aggregating some data but not others. If you group by only 1 of those 2 columns which value should it return for the non-grouped column? But of course you tagged this with both mysql and sql server. mysql allows this and calls it a feature....but it is a logical bug. sql server does not allow this and raises an error.

Comment: change it to Min(Mdate) if Mdate is always the same for all matchid

Comment: Countless blogs on the net will give you details on this, examples - https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/everything-about-group-by   /   https://teamsql.io/blog/?p=1028   /   https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/04/do-you-really-understand-sqls-group-by-and-having-clauses/

Comment: If you're not using Microsoft SQL Server (and your error message indicates that you're not) then please remove the "SQL-Server" tag.